# Проблема с остановкой плеера Android

Tags: java, android

Имею стриминговый плеер, запускаю в `AsyncTask`, проблема в том, что при сворачивании приложения, видимо при не хватке памяти система останавливает его и время всегда разное, так же при запуске тяжелых приложений так же останавливается. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [**AsynkTask** - deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

   > This class was deprecated in API level 30.    Use the standard
   > `java.util.concurrent` or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.
2. Для работы задача в фоне таких как воспроизведение музыки используются [**Services**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru).

   **Service** является компонентом приложения, который может выполнять длительные операции в фоновом режиме и не содержит пользовательского интерфейса. Другой компонент приложения может запустить службу, которая продолжит работу в фоновом режиме даже в том случае, когда пользователь перейдет в другое приложение. Кроме того, компонент может привязаться к службе для взаимодействия с ней и даже выполнять межпроцессное взаимодействие (IPC). Например, служба может обрабатывать сетевые транзакции, воспроизводить музыку, выполнять ввод-вывод файла или взаимодействовать с поставщиком контента, и все это в фоновом режиме.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, а могу ли я как-то тогда передать туда данные, например, поток из класса плеера?

Comment: Я плохо понимаю, о каком потоке идет речь. Но внутри сервиса вы можете запускать свои потоки. Так же вы можете туда передавать данные и взаимодействовать с остальными частями программы. В целом все програмы которые работают в фоне более нескольких секунд используют сервисы (музыка, загрузка больших файлов, навигаторы и т.д)

Comment: Имею ввиду именно передачу данных в сервис для его работы

Comment: Ну конечно можно. https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/ Вот тут вроде бы то что вам нужно или то что сможет помочь.